# Passing the date after selecting it from the calendar

Tags: android, date

everyone I am encountering a problem with passing the date from the calendar to my Create_Event.class. Initially the date textView displays "text" then when I click the "Select the date" button the calendar page will show and the date is supposed to be passed to textView that originally displays "text". I tried coding using intent.putExtra to pass the date from the calendar page to the Create_Events page but I got a force close error due to NullPointerException. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks a lot.

For reference, the codes:

Calendar.java

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String date_month_year = (String)view.getTag();
                    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Selected:").append(date_month_year));

                    Intent k = new Intent(Calendar_Event.this, Create_Events.class);
                    k.putExtra("passdate", date_month_year);
                 startActivity(k);
```

Create_Event.java

```
 Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if(intent == null)
        {
         String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("passdate");
         TextView txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
         txtDate.setText(strdata);
         }
        else
        {

        }
```

***Originally the if(intent == null) is if(intent != null), I thought changing it would work but it doesn't. :P

Updated the logcat:

```
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.page/main.page.Create_Events}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at main.page.Create_Events.onCreate(Create_Events.java:261)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-07 12:03:28.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

[image]     [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again.

Updated:

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
    if(bundle != null)
    {

        String date = bundle.getString("date");
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        txtDate.setText(date);          
    }
```

Comment: Where you get error ? Can you post logcat error ?

Comment: I get the error when I want to open the Create_Events page. The nullPointerException error will appear onCreate, the line of codes above.

Comment: what code is on Line Number 261 Create_Events.java:261 ?

Comment: It's String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("passdate"); then now I have changed the codes according to your answer, the page runs but when I selected the date and re-direct to the Create_Events page the textView for the date disappear.

Comment: Make sure textView is not invisible.

Comment: The textview is visible. It disappear when I selected the date and the textview is gone.

Comment: Updated with the codes I edited.

Comment: Initialize textview before initialize bundle.
TextView txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: I changed already but the textView is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bundle in Create_Events Activity to get date. Before passing data you first need to check it is null or not.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle != null)
{
    String date = bundle.getString("passdate");
}
```

> Bundle generally use for passing data between various Activities. It
>   depends on you what type of values you want to pass but bundle can
>   hold all types of values and pass to the new activity.