# TextView won't show the data that is being passed from another activity

Tags: android, date

I have encountered a problem with passing data from another activity to the current one. Actually, I have asked another question regarding the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311497/passing-the-date-after-selecting-it-from-the-calendar) and now the problem is that the textView for the date become empty and I don't know what's wrong. Anyone could help me with this problem? Thanks a lot and I will really appreciate any help that I can get.

UPDATED:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
if(bundle != null)
{

    String date = bundle.getString("date");

    txtDate.setText(date);          
}
```

when I run this, the textView won't show anything. Can anyone help me? Thanks again.

Comment: are you sure date contains any value ? put a log and check and if you have multiple textviews make sure you are using the right id for txtDate

Comment: Hi, may I know where should I put the log at? In the date button?

Comment: You have to put log in second activity where you get date from bundle . Log.i("=============== Date"," :: "+date);

Comment: Hi, eh I put the log alrdy but the textView is still empty.

Comment: chk your logcat please and tell what you have against Date

Comment: Eh hi, may I know what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String date = bundle.getString("date");

check whether the **"date"** that you are using as a **key** here in getString() is same to what you are using when you send the value from the previous activity.. for e.g,

**Previous Activity** = i.putExtra("date","_yourvalue");

**Next Activity** = Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                    String date = bundle.getString("date");

If that is same then check whether you have initialised your textview properly using the following,

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewbyID(R.id.yourID);

then do

tv.setText(date);

And all of this must be done in the onCreate of the activity....

Let me know if the problem still persists..

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It works! I guess I mixed up the codes that's why it can't work previously. Followed your suggestions and the date shows already. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with your casting the view to String!

Write the type of view in place of the ***String***

```
String date_month_year = (String)view.getTag();
```

Comment: huh? I don't get you. You mean I should type according to what you did above?

Comment: you have written the above line in onClick.. right? 

tell me whose onClick is that? (i mean which View )

Comment: he updated the question right now... i was confused with the link he posted in the question!